# What is the signal emitted when we close a Window in qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have my MainWindow that open a second Window.

When I click on a button in my second window, a thread is launched and I want my thread to end when I quit my second window.

What is the signal emitted when my SecondWindow is closed ?

Thank you for your futures answers

Comment: Your second window can be a QDialog and you can connect your MainWindow to the second QDialog Window with ```accepted(), finished(int result) or rejected()``` signals

Answer (score 14):

There is no signal emitted when widgets (including QMainWindows) are closed. If a widget is set to be deleted when it is closed then you could use the following QObject signal to detect when the widget is about to be destroyed...

```
void    destroyed(QObject *obj = Q_NULLPTR)
```

However this will only work if your window has the Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose flag enabled (it is not enabled by default).

Alternatively and probably more preferably you can implement the standard widget close event and emit your own signal to indicate that the window was closed:

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent( QCloseEvent* event )
{
    emit MySignalToIndicateThatTheWindowIsClosing();
    event->accept();
}
```

Comment: The fact that Qt doesn't emit this kind of signal by default makes me wonder if it is bad practice to implement it by hand. Seems like basic functionality to me.